# Aligning the background box with text on canvas

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I am using the following code:

```
function measureText(text, font) {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    Object.assign(span.style, {
        font: font,
        margin: '0',
        padding: '0',
        border: '0',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
    });
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    const {width, height} = span.getBoundingClientRect();
    span.remove();
    return {width, height};
}

function drawTextBG(ctx, txt, font, x, y) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = font;
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = 'center';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';  
  var dimen = measureText(txt, font)
  var height = dimen['height']
  var width = dimen['width']
  ctx.fillRect(x - width/2, y-height/2, width, parseInt(font, 10));
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

I get the following image where the white back ground is not perfectly capturing the text. How do I modify my code to get the text within the white background aligned perfectly.

I want to dynamically create the height of the background box also.

A working sandbox code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-night-599p2?fontsize=14)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting padding:"5%" could do the job, I just test it[here] (https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-sanderson-bwl8h?fontsize=14) and looks nice.